# Can't mount a SSD

Tags: mount, ssd

I have a bit of a problem. I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on my laptop, and about 2 years ago I replaced the aging HDD with a 32 GB SSD. Today I tried to boot my computer, but it couldn't.

So I've put the SSD into an external HDD rack and booted a live CD Ubuntu 10.10 to try to recover data from the SSD. The SSD appears in the drop down menu but it won't mount.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 2125.445659] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] 62533296 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 GB/29.8 GiB)
[ 2125.446983] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[ 2125.446988] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 17 00 00 08
[ 2125.446992] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2125.449084] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2125.449098]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[ 2125.454285] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2125.454293] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2125.777836] JBD: no valid journal superblock found
[ 2125.777840] EXT4-fs (sda1): error loading journal
```

Is there a way to solve this issue so I can recover the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
e4fsck -f /dev/sda1
```

This is will check the drive and attempt to repair it.